# Javascript's slice doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I declared some global variables in a PHP file:

```
var coordinates = [];
var joined_data = [];
```

The variable *coordinates* is initially set with some data received from a XMLHttpRequest and *joined_data* is set to be equal to *coordinates*.
Later on, a function is invoked:

```
function addMarkerToWps(wp_id)
{
    joined_data = coordinates.slice(0, coordinates.length-5);
    calculateRoutes();

}
```

This short code should select a subarray and save it into *joined_data*; the function *calculateRoutes* draws a path on the map using Google APIs; at the end of such function, I try to display the lengths of two arrays and I expected *joined_data* to be shorter than *coordinates*, but I discovered they have same size.
So, I suspect that *slice* function failed somehow. 
Here's the function *calculateRoutes*:

```
function calculateRoutes()
{
    // remove previous route
    removeRoutes();
    //window.alert('Numero punti ' + coordinates.length);

    // set start position
    //var begin = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[0].Lat, coordinates[0].Lon);
    var begin = new google.maps.LatLng(joined_data[0].Lat, joined_data[0].Lon);

    // set end position
    var end = null;

    // waypoints struct
    var waypoints = [];

    // counter
    var wCount = 0;

    // loop
    var i;
    //for(i=1; i<coordinates.length-1; i++)
    for(i=1; i<joined_data.length-1; i++)
    {
        if(wCount === REQUEST_WAYPOINTS_LIMIT)
        {
            // increment counter to get end's index
            i++;

            // set end
            //end = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[i].Lat, coordinates[i].Lon);
            end = new google.maps.LatLng(joined_data[i].Lat, joined_data[i].Lon);

            // draw current route
            drawRoute(begin, end, waypoints);

            // update indeces
            begin = end;

            // reset structures
            wCount = 0;
            waypoints = [];
        }

        // add waypoint to list
        waypoints.push
        (
            {
                //location: new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[i].Lat, coordinates[i].Lon),
                location: new google.maps.LatLng(joined_data[i].Lat, joined_data[i].Lon),
                stopover: true
            }
        );

        // increments counter
        wCount++;
    }

    if(waypoints.length > 0)
    {
        //end = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[coordinates.length-1].Lat, coordinates[coordinates.length-1].Lon);
        end = new google.maps.LatLng(joined_data[joined_data.length-1].Lat, joined_data[joined_data.length-1].Lon);
        drawRoute(begin, end, waypoints);
    }

    for(var i = 0; i<coordinates.length; i++)
    {
        placeMarker(coordinates[i].Lat, coordinates[i].Lon, "http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markers/red/blank.png");
    }

    for(var j = 0; j<interest_points.length; j++)
    {
        placeAttractionMarker(
            interest_points[j].Lat,
            interest_points[j].Lon,
            "http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markers/orange/blank.png",
            interest_points[j].Name,
            interest_points[j].Wikipedia,
            j

        );
    }

    //joinData();
    //window.alert("" + coordinates.length + " " + interest_points.length + " " + joined_data.length);
    window.alert("" + coordinates.length + " " + joined_data.length);


}
```

Can you spot the error? thank you.

Comment: We'd need some code to spot the error. Can you reproduce the problem in a fiddle ? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: slice function doesn't fail. what i feel is.. the array length what you are requesting is not that much.. means if the array length is 3.. you limit it to 3-5. which is -2.. which cannot be indexed and sliced..

Comment: i tried coordinates.length-5, too, knowing it should work since coordinates array has initially 8 elements, but nothing changed.
Regarding my problem, coordinates' array contains a set of coordinates to be shown on a map. now, I'm trying to show on the map only a subset of coordinates

Comment: Nothing too suspicious in given code. For debugging, you could add `console.log(coordinates.length, joined_data.length);` to second row in addMarkerToWps (just before calling calculateRoutes();) and to first line of calculateRoutes - what results are you getting from those? As one possible explanation, variable scope may cause such behavior, but it's not possible to tell without seeing full code.

Comment: @ameenulla0007 - it's possible to use negative indexes in slice as well, to select from end of array. So syntax is correct and new array, shorter than original one, should be returned in every cases.